# Join a table on itself vs. to itself?

Tags: sql, terminology, self-join

Not extremely significant... but I've gotten a bit curious: What's the correct terminology for a self-join - do you join a table *on* itself, or join a table *to* itself?

Comment: @spiny, I like that; think we can get a new keyword added to the SQL standard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You join it **to** itself, **on** the fields being joined.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely to get various answers since I'm not sure there's a "standard" per se, but I think `SELF JOIN` is pretty common, not to mention self-explanatory. And yes, you join it **TO** itself.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you join a table to itself

I would only use on to refer to the fields being joined

Answer (score 1):

I am gonna go all mavericky and say `WITH`. But, since JOIN is itself a verb, you do not need anything more than that:

```
TableA joins TableA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.FIELD, B.FIELD
FROM MYTABLE A, MYTABLE B
WHERE A.PK = B.FK
```